# Calling JavaScript code from MVC form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a JavaScript code that has to be event driven by clicking the submit button on a form in an mvc view page. How do I code this into the form's onClick event listener. Thanks.

html form --

```
<form>
   <!-- form code -->
 <button class="btn btn-alt" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript --

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $YR.WK.trackPage({
        "orderId": "1234",
        "tax": "99.99",
        "shipping": "9.99",
        "total": "109.98",
        "city": "NYC",
        "state": "NY",
        "country": "USA",
        "currency": "USD",
        "email": document.getElementByName('Email').value,
        "locale": "en_US"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Learn to setup a click event listener or, even better, a submit even listener. There's mountains of information on how to do this all over the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an Id to your button.

```
<button class="btn btn-alt" id="myBtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Now you can attache an eventListener to this button element.

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
     alert("clicked");
     // you can execute your other js code here.
}, false);
```

That is vanilla javascript. If you have jQuery library included in your page, It is even more easy

```
$(function(){

  $("#myBtn").click(function(e){
    alert("Clicked");
  });

});
```

Comment: I have jQuery library on the page. Where should I place my JavaScript code? Thanks.

Comment: in layout/ current view, possible under scripts section

Comment: Just post a question with minimal relevant details and you will get help from users of SO.